# Не могу разобраться с чужим кодом для поиска данных в процессе

Tags: c++, память, процесс, static, inline

Мне нужно найти конкретные данные, которые программа откладывает во время работы. (На подобии cheat engine) Я начал искать код который касается конкретно моей программы. Столкнулся вот с такой строкой и вообще не понимаю что она может значить:

```
static inline LPCSTR entitylist= "\x0E\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x39\x40\x9A\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xE9\x3F";
```

Подскажите.

Comment: Строка для поиска, но в шетснадцатеричном формате - каждое `\x##` представляет собой символ с ASCII-кодом `##` в шестнадцатеричной записи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На том сайте, на котором вы скорей всего нашли эту строчку (я думаю я нашел этот сайт) это означает `"сигнатура поиска"`, а если я не ошибся сайтом, то ниже можно увидеть примерно такую же строчку и это уже `"сигнатура замены"`.

Вкратце `сигнатура` - набор байтов для определенного значения в программе. Как раз в строчке у вас и записаны байты.

Если хотите почитать об этом, то в интернете есть куча сайтов, даже на русском. Я конечно же не буду выкладывать сюда ссылки, чтобы не распространять такие вещи :)